# Android Context after Activity is finished and Services are still running

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-context

My Activity starts the service and finishes (while service is still running in background). What context does the service have after activity is finished?

I need to have only the service running. In fact I don't need any activity - it is used just for starting of service.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (!BootDemoService.isInstanceCreated()) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, BootDemoService.class);
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }

        this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'what context does the service have after Activity is finished?' The service has its own `Context`, this doesn't change just because some `Activity` is gone.

Answer (score 0):

in you case the same context should be ApplicationContext.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext()